# What can an Android app without added permissions do?

Tags: android

I've read on [androidcentral](https://www.androidcentral.com/security-scare-week-what-can-app-no-permissions-do) that an application without added permissions can access `/data/system/packages.list`, `/proc`, and files on the SD card. The article is five years old so maybe something has changed.

So, on current versions of Android, which files and which functions can an app without additional permissions use?

Answer (score 1):

Androids security model is such that each app runs in its own sandbox, and access to anything outside that sandbox is a permission that needs to be granted by the system.

There are a few categories of permissions, and those that fall into the "normal" category are allowed without user choice. An example is access to the internet.

Access that poses a risk to the user's system or user's privacy are not "normal" and are termed "dangerous" and have to be approved by the user.

https://www.kaspersky.com/blog/android-permissions-guide/14014/
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html